# How to enable javascript in HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit-driver

This is my coding for HtmlUnit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.setTimeout(20000);
//webClient.setSSLClientCertificate(certificateUrl,
       certificatePassword, certificateType);
HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("http://oneurl");
```

But i got error like

```
WARN APOPERATOR "htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl" Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
ERROR APOPERATOR "javascript.StrictErrorReporter" runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://easypay.swisscom.ch/charging-engine-checkout/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] line=[3] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
WARN APOPERATOR "html.HTMLDocument" getElementById(sizzle-1447848465222) did a getElementByName for Internet Explorer
WARN APOPERATOR "htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl" Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
```

Can anyone please help to enable javascript in HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 4):

This already enables the JavaScript:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

What you see in the logs are warning messages that the content type should not be used, but you can safely ignore them.